# How to use class attribute in its instance method in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I want to use `variation` attribute inside `to_representation` function in `serializers.py`. When I tried to implement it an error occured. I think I still don't understand the fundamental of Python class.
Here's my `serializers.py`:

```
class MarketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    regions = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Region.objects.all())
    languages = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Language.objects.all())
    variation = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_product_variations')

    class Meta:
        model = Market
        fields = ['id', 'regions', 'languages', 'name', 'status', 'variation']
        depth = 1

    @staticmethod
    def get_product_variations(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(distributor__region__market=self).distinct().count()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        if self.context['request'].method == 'GET':
            regions = RegionSerializer(instance.regions, many=True).data
            languages = LanguageSerializer(instance.languages, many=True).data

            data = {
                'id': instance.id,
                'regions': regions,
                'languages': languages,
                'name': instance.name,
                'status': instance.status,
                'variation': self.variation,
            }
            return data
        return Serializer.to_representation(self, instance)
```

`'variation': self.variation` gives me this error on browsable API:

> AttributeError at /api/markets/
>   'MarketSerializer' object has no attribute 'variation'

While `'variation': MarketSerializer.variation` and `'variation': self.__class__.variation` give me this error:

> AttributeError at /api/markets/
>   type object 'MarketSerializer' has no attribute 'variation'

**Edit**
`'variation': variation` gives me this error:

> NameError at /api/markets/
>   name 'variation' is not defined

Comment: DRF does some black magic with serializer attributes. But you still call your method directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how this suppose to work:

```
@staticmethod
def get_product_variations(self):
    return Product.objects.filter(distributor__region__market=self).distinct().count()
```

Because, in serializer method field, the method should be like this:

```
def get_product_variations(self, obj):
    # not a static method
    return Product.objects.filter(distributor__region__market=obj).distinct().count()
```

Similarly, you can use that method in `to_represent` method:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
  ...
  data = {
            'id': instance.id,
            'regions': regions,
            'languages': languages,
            'name': instance.name,
            'status': instance.status,
            'variation': self.get_product_variations(instance),
        }
 ...
```

Or better:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
      data = super().to_representation(instance)
      if self.context['request'].method == 'GET':
            data['regions'] = RegionSerializer(instance.regions, many=True).data
            data['languages'] = LanguageSerializer(instance.languages, many=True).data
      return data
```

Comment: previously get_product_variations wasn't staticmethod. Because when I tried to call it inside data = { '...': ..., } it said get_product_variations expected 2 arguments. And I only fill it with 1 argument which is instance. The auto-solution PyCharm gave me is to implement it with @staticmethod.

Comment: well, did you use `self.get_product_variations(instance)`? `get_product_variations` is a object method here. BTW, I would recommend to use 2nd solution as its much cleaner

Comment: Yes. I tried to use `self.get_product_variations(instance)` inside data = { }. It also can't be used in the class attribute `variation = ...` if I didn't apply the staticmethod. It gave me this error 
Exception Value: 
get_product_variations() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: ruddra, I forgot to reply about the second solution. Thank you so much. I like it and using it now. Btw I think you mistyped `data = super().to_represent(instance)`. Isn't it should be `data = super().to_representation(instance)` ? Or they're indeed different methods.

Comment: No, it should be to_representation. I am fixing it now

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to access the outer class instance from an inner class, use factory-method to build Inner instance and pass Outer instance to it.
We can not guarantee the existence of an outer class when you create an instance of the inner class

```
class MarketSerializer(object):
    variation = 'h'

    def MarketSerializer(self):
        return MarketSerializer.Meta(self)

    class Meta(object):
        def __init__(self, market_serializer_instance):
            self.market_serializer_instance = market_serializer_instance

        def inner_method(self):
            print(self.market_serializer_instance.variation)
```

Comment: I got new error:  
Exception Type: NameError  
Exception Value: name 'variation' is not defined

Comment: Marlon, your answer works! Thank you. Although I was a bit confuse why there's no `model` and `fields` attributes inside `class Meta(object)`.

Comment: I only explained the idea. Had no time to include all your code in it. :p BTW I personally don't recommend nested classes since it does not depict any relationship, does it?

Comment: "Since you are trying to access the outer class instance from an inner class" => where have you seen this ?

Comment: "BTW I personally don't recommend nested classes" => this is part of the DRF serializers framework (and based on Django's Model and ModelForm idioms). The inner class is a namespace used by the metaclass (Python metaclass).